# Web-beautify JS code on Windows (js-beautify for unminimifying)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to un-minimify JS code on Windows.
I've installed [web-beautify](https://github.com/yasuyk/web-beautify/tree/e1b45321d8c11b404b12c8e55afe55eaa7c84ee9) from MELPA.
I also installed [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) for Windows, which is a dependency of this package.
I then `ran npm -g install js-beautify` as instructed. The command completed well.
Howevever, calling web-beautify-js on a js buffer still does not work.

The program js-beautify works on my command-line tools, but not in my Emacs Shells, even though the variables (PATH and exec-path) are well set. I suspect this comes from the fact that js-beautify is in fact a Batch script which calls the program node, with an argument. I don't know why, but the batch script does not work from an emacs shell - except if I call it from its directory

It is possible though to reproduce the behaviour of the script in an Emacs Shell anywhere. For instance, although typing js-beautify  does not work, the following command worked:

```
node <path-to-npm>\node_modules\js-beautify\js\bin\js-beautify.js <file>
```

However, I have no idea how to go any further. What I want is not to be able to call js-beautify from an Emacs shell, but to be able to call web-beautify-js from any js buffer.
Has anyone found a clean hack to do this?

(Error message on web-beautify-js:

`'js-beautify' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

)

Comment: An "emacs shell" is `M-x shell`?

Comment: Yes, either M-x shell or M-x eshell, both have the same behaviour on this issue.